# Need url (demo) for Ups Shipment Api Integration

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I just need shipment tracking and request Api Link/ any code.

**Here is Demo Code:**
i get no authenication carrier.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'ShippoToken ,<shippo_test_7406cb4031cd20465ee984a6b65595bef87cfbf8>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = [
  ('amount', '2000'),
  ('currency', 'usd'),
  ('source', 'tok_amex'),
  ('metadata[order_id]', '6735'),]
response = requests.post('https://api.goshippo.com/shipments/', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.json())
```